# sqlite3 - Generating a unique ID based on existing fields

Tags: sqlite

I've got a sql script that creates tables, sets up triggers[1] and inserts data. The sql is used via the sqlite command line to create a database during the build of my application. Basically I have a table that whos rows must be unique based on three fields. I would like to automatically generate a hash or some form of unique ID based on the three fields to use as a primary key. My understanding is sqlite has no built in hashing functions. Is there an other means to generate a unique key based on the contents of three fields in a before insert trigger?

```
[1] This isn't happening yet as I don't know how to generate a unique key
```

The table looks something like this. I could use a primary key of the 3 fields (firstName, lastName, birthYear) but then I would have to use all three in each table I wanted to have a foreign key in. With the 3 fields being strings I imagine that it would be a lot more space and would slow things down.

```
create table (
  firstName VARCHAR,
  lastName  VARCHAR,
  birthYear CHAR(4)
  ... more fields ...
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, it is preferred that you use a single, auto-increment integer column as the primary key. Natural keys are then modeled adding a `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  firstName VARCHAR,
  lastName  VARCHAR,
  birthYear CHAR(4)
  UNIQUE (firstName, lastName, birthYear)
);
```

This way, you can use the value of `id` as the foreign key for other tables, while the `UNIQUE` constraint prevents you from having duplicate records with the same natural key.

Comment: This works to keep the fields unique and it gives me an ID to use but the id is not based on the 3 fields in question. For example if I create my database, then come back at a later time and add some more data and regenerate my database the IDs may be different between each run.

Comment: I am not sure whether I fully understand. So you mean you need the IDs to be reproducible? What would you be using them for? I am not very familiar with triggers, but at least for the foreign key problem the above solution should suffice.

Comment: Yeah, I'de like them to be reproducible. I create a database to send off in my app, but I need to be able to sync it with the users local cache during application updates. I need to make sure the keys don't clash.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not sufficient to create a primary key from these three columns?

```
create table test(a int, b int, c int, primary key(a,b,c));
```

Comment: ChrisB, I could but see my edit why I don't like this approach.

Comment: It sounds like you are building this database from a script external to sqlite. If so, how about generating a hash using a different command line program like md5sum? Then, just pass that to sqlite as a normal primary key